# Boolean expression in CASE in WHERE clause does not work

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, firebird, firebird2.5

I am having problems with Firebird SQL statement in version Firebird 2.5.

Based on today's date, I have to select either this month's data or the previous month's data.

```
SELECT * FROM FA_DOBAVNICA
WHERE
1=1

AND CASE WHEN
    extract(day from cast('Now' as date)) < 9
THEN
   DATUM_NAROCILA BETWEEN 'start of previous month' AND 'end of previous month'
ELSE
   DATUM_NAROCILA BETWEEN 'start of this month' AND 'end of this month'
END
```

I am getting a `104` error `Token unknown for BETWEEN`. I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Which Firebird version?

Comment: added in the question. I applogize

Comment: Firebird 2.5 has no booleans so you cannot make a boolean expression to be result of CASE function. That's the problem with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you can rephrase it with an or clause like this and it should do the job:

```
SELECT * FROM FA_DOBAVNICA
WHERE
1=1
AND 
((extract(day from cast('Now' as date)) < 9 AND DATUM_NAROCILA BETWEEN 'start of previous month' AND 'end of previous month')
or
(extract(day from cast('Now' as date)) > 8 AND DATUM_NAROCILA BETWEEN 'start of this month' AND 'end of this month'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would avoid forking out conditions variants in `where` and make it two queries instead. I suspect conditional `where` might suppress Firebird's query optimizer, and two distinct queries connected together might end up with a better *query plan* using indexes.

Especially if you have more conditions than actually shown there which `1=1` placeholder implies. You have to check and compare real plans using you real data and real added conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM FA_DOBAVNICA 
WHERE extract(day from cast('Now' as date)) < 9
  AND DATUM_NAROCILA BETWEEN 'start of previous month' AND 'end of previous'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM FA_DOBAVNICA 
WHERE extract(day from cast('Now' as date)) >= 9 
  AND DATUM_NAROCILA BETWEEN 'start of this month' AND 'end of this month'
```

However in your specific case - why using `CASE` at all? Why not computing the target date span instead?

```
WITH 
 TargetDay as 
   (SELECT DATEADD( -8 DAY TO CURRENT_DATE) AS TPoint FROM RDB$DATABASE)
,TargetStart as
   (SELECT DATEADD( 1 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM TPoint) DAY TO TPoint) AS TStart FROM TargetDay)
,TargetEnd as
   (SELECT DATEADD( -1 DAY TO DATEADD( 1 MONTH TO TStart)) AS TEnd FROM TargetStart)
   
select TStart, TEnd, TPoint from TargetStart, TargetEnd, TargetDay
```

| TSTART | TEND | TPOINT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31 | 2021-08-03 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=c1be5f543f7bb53fbb7d5ea8b7ad13c0)*

See? you do not need any if-then-else at all!

Added bonus is that you now can easily turn your `9` into an SQL parameter, rather than having it a literal constant injected into SQL code via always [fragile string splicing](https://www.bobby-tables.com), because now you only use `9` once in your query, thus you no more have have to care about changing two different parameters/constants in a query always in sync.

```
WITH 
 TargetDay as 
   (SELECT DATEADD( 1 - (cast( ? as integer )) DAY TO CURRENT_DATE) AS TPoint FROM RDB$DATABASE)
,TargetStart as....
```

Or in languages like Delphi which simulate named parameters for Firebird, it can be like

```
WITH 
 TargetDay as 
   (SELECT DATEADD( 1 - (cast( :ThresholdDay as integer )) DAY TO CURRENT_DATE) AS TPoint FROM RDB$DATABASE)
,TargetStart as....
```